# How can I mount an LCD TV onto the *wall* of an RV?

Tags: mounting

I have an RV and I want to mount a flat panel LCV TV onto the *wall* of the RV. Most people who put LCD's into their RVs put them up above the driver where wooden cabinetry exists, but I do not want to do that.

I want to mount the TV onto the wall of the RV, but I cannot find information about the nature of the walls -- are there studs, and if so, how far apart, how uniform, and of what material? Aside from studs, how much can the wall itself hold? What materials are made to even *construct* RV walls?

So ... how can I mount a 42-inch LCD TV onto the wall of my RV? And along with that, any information you can provide or point to about how RV walls are constructed would be most appreciated!

Comment: Found [this](http://www.fulltimeroadwarriors.com/2011/03/our-bedroom-tv-wall-mount-in-rv.html)

Comment: My brother rebuilt the interior of his caravan and I would imagine caravans would be build with similar techniques and materials to motorhomes/RVs. When he pulled the interior plywood wall off, he found timber studs between them and the outer wall. However, many were not load-bearing: they were just there for a gap between the walls, often just to provide a cavity for the wiring.

Comment: [This image](http://www.google.com/url?source=imglanding&ct=img&q=http://www.serenitysys.com/rv/arctic_fox_29v/29V_assembly_line/DSC_7880%20(Medium).JPG&sa=X&ei=PrHgToC-N4jsggfwiPCvBg&ved=0CAwQ8wc&usg=AFQjCNGEb6YLnsuLJKm1zf40IJGW0t3Ytw) might help.

Comment: Interior or exterior wall?

Comment: @gregmac - exterior wall (meaning, the TV will be inside, but mounted to the wall that is part of the exterior of the rv).

Comment: Depends on the RV as to what the wall construction is made up of.

Answer (score 4):

Best bet - call the dealer or find the manual. Chopping up something like this is a risky proposition without documentation (manuals) or a knowledgeable tech because while you may find something with a stud finder you have no way of cutting into it and making sure you are not cutting into wiring/plumbing/vents/etc. Unless you want to pull the entire wall or rent an ir/magnetic camrea, you cannot do this with absolute certainty.

Comment: 2nding the contact a dealer.  Most dealers also do upgrades and things.  You don't have to necessarily have them do it for you, just go in and ask about it. There may exist a good solution already.  I can't imagine that you want to just attach it yourself anyplace that their isn't already re-enforcing for a cabinent or something.  The walls of RV's aren't really load bearing and are only re-enforced at specific places.

Comment: +1: having watched "How It's Made" segments featuring RV's, I doubt there's much real structure in the walls.

Comment: no reason for there to be, now I think about it - not a lot of load in the roof to support.